# I want to add a custom "all posts by author" by authors name. How?

Tags: templates

I have a custom display of meta-info (authors name, date and categories). So, I want to display a custom link to all posts by author. By theme default I have this `<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>` which displays author name and if you press on it you get what I want. On the index.php actually it is what I want, but on single.php I would like to have something like "view all pages by author" text and if you would press on it, it should do exactly the same as adding `<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>.` where should I start with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that if your blog is hosted on wordpress.com

Comment: I have a custom host

Comment: Then why did you tag the question with 'wordpress.com'? Anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Attach a filter that only outputs a different link when you're on single.php:

```
function wpse25725_author_posts( $link )
{
    // abort if not on single.php
    if ( ! is_single() )
        return;

    // modify this as you like - so far exactly the same as in the original core function
    // if you simply want to add something to the existing link, use ".=" instead of "=" for $link
    $link = sprintf(
        '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a>',
        get_author_posts_url( $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Posts by %s' ), get_the_author() ) ),
        get_the_author()
    );

    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'the_author_posts_link', 'wpse25725_author_posts' );
```